# Is it possible to exchange information between arduino and android phones easily using nrf24l01?

Tags: android, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-due

I need to send information from arduino to an android phone, having some app actively listening for radio communication from arduino. Using nrf24l01 is that possible?

The best scenario would be direct communication, even without any type of handshake. Arduino sends a number sequence that android expects to receive, and the app alerts me when it ears that sequence.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no Android phones have a nrf24l01 module nor SPI, so you will have to create an interface adapter. So... You can decide what communication you want to use.

e.g. Android phone <-> USB/UART converter <-> microcontroller <-> nRF24L01

and, since you are designing your own interface, you will be able to create the proper protocol.